# Any idea why I can't seem to execute two Get-WMIObject commands in the same Scriptblock?

Tags: powershell

I'm having a hell of a time with what seems like an utterly bizarre issue.  I'm basically trying to inventory a bunch of workstations via WinRM and the `Invoke-Command` PowerShell cmdlet, but I'm running into grief when I try to execute more than one `Get-WMIObject` call at a time.

In this case, I'm specifically trying to get the model and serial number of the workstations and pipe them out to a CSV, making it important that the two commands are executed in the same Scriptblock, giving me something very similar to the below, basically.

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Model ; Get-WmiObject win32_SystemEnclosure | Select serialnumber } -ComputerName (Get-ADComputer -Server [domain I care about] -filter 'name -Like "[types of computers I care about]"' | Select-Object -expand Name)
```

Even when run locally, `Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Model ; Get-WmiObject win32_SystemEnclosure | Select serialnumber` only returns the first command.  I've tried swapping them around and the first command executes, while the second does not.  Some of my colleagues report that it works just fine for them, others see the same result as me, and it doesn't seem to be a version issue, as one of the people for whom this works is running the same version of PowerShell as I am.  (5.0.10240.16384)

Screenshot below of a few different command combinations. Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the list in the select-object cmdlets so both include the properties output by each, you will get the result you want (I think).

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Model,SerialNumber ; Get-WmiObject win32_SystemEnclosure | Select model,serialnumber } -ComputerName localhost
```

That will get you output to the screen which should include all of the info.  If you just want objects you can just capture the output and see that all of the properties are there.

```
$objects=Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Model ; Get-WmiObject win32_SystemEnclosure | Select serialnumber } -ComputerName (Get-ADComputer -Server [domain I care about] -filter 'name -Like "[types of computers I care about]"' | Select-Object -expand Name)
```

If you `execute $objects | format-list *` you will see that you have two objects, one with a Model and one with a SerialNumber.

Outputting different objects to a single CSV is another issue altogether.  You get columns in the CSV based on the properties in the *first* object, so you will lose the SerialNumber property in the CSV.

Comment: That is an interesting approach, and kind of works, but it doesn't quite export right.  Piping that to a CSV or variable results in a blank SerialNumber value.  I'll see what I can do with it, though.